# laravel 4 how to show result at the same page and how to solve circle invoke

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am totally new to laravel, I am now want to use laravel 4.

Suppose I have a page A.php, and it contains a form & a submit button. After I submit the post request to B.php, and in B.php I query data from database.

My question is I want to show my result on B.php , that it is to say the same page of A.php request, how do I write in routes.php.

My code:
master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
       <metacharset="UTF-8">
       <title>course query</title>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('container')
        </div>

        <h1 class="ret">The result is:
            @yield('ret')
            <input id="result" type="text"/>
        </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

A.php

```
@extends('course.master')

@section('container')
    <h1>My Courses</h1>
    {{Form::open(array('url' => 'csOp'))}}
        {{Form::label('course', 'Your course')}}
        {{Form::text('course')}}
        {{Form::submit('Submit')}}
    {{Form::close()}}
@endsection
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('course', function(){
    return View::make('course.B');
});

Route::post('csOp', function(){
    // do something
    //$inputCourse = Input::get('course');    
    //$records = Courses::where('name', '=', $inputCourse)->get();

    // how do I return
    //return View::make('csOp', $records);
});
```

As you can see, in A.php I have a form and request to `csOp`

```
Form::open(array('url' => 'csOp')
```

csOp is B.php, and in B.php I query data from db, and now I got the results,
but how can I put result to the page (B.php) itself? That it is to say I want to put the result to

```
<input id="result" type="text"/>
```

You know in jquery is easy, how do I use it in laravel 4 ?

And if return to csOp, absolutlly will get an error, it is in a  circle. So how can I solve it ?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to populate a form based on model contents, i,e. populate form using database data.

So in laravel you can use [Form Model Binding](http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding). To do so, use the `Form::model` method. so in your case

```
Route::post('csOp', function(){
// do something
$inputCourse = Input::get('course');    
$records = Courses::where('name', '=', $inputCourse)->get();

// how do I return
return View::make('csOp')->with('records',$records);
});
```

And your `csOp.blade.php`

```
@extends('course.master')

@section('container')
<h1>My Courses</h1>
{{Form::model($records,array('url' => 'csOp'))}}
    {{Form::label('course', 'Your course')}}
    {{Form::text('course')}}

{{Form::close()}}
@endsection
```

Now, when you generate a form element, like a text input, the model's value matching the field's name will automatically be set as the field value. So, for example, for a text input named course, the Courses model's course attribute would be set as the value.